# How to visualize different stages in Caffe net?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, protocol-buffers, caffe

I am developing all-in-one net with Caffe. I've figured out how I can use stages to separate train+test and deploy. However, I'd like to visualize stages.

Currently I've got the following code in the Jupyter notebook (old one, copied from some response here, taking into account different `prototxt` files for train and deploy)

```
from google.protobuf import text_format
from IPython import display
import caffe.draw

trained_net = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
text_format.Merge(open('train_val.prototxt').read(), trained_net)

display.Image(caffe.draw.draw_net(trained_net, 'BT'))
```

Some layers in my new `train_val_deploy.prototxt file` contain

```
include {
     stage: "create"
}
```

and

```
include {
     stage: "deploy"
}
```

How can I draw these stages?